# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to Host this website in IIS and run, but it is showing

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error".

I have change applicationHost.config file but that doesn't help. When I am running the project from Visual Studio 15 it runs properly but when I publish the project and host in IIS it gives this same error ("HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error")

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `applicationHost.config` ?

Comment: 500 internal server error simply means the application crashed somehow, but the cause could be almost anything. Check your Windows Event Logs on the server for any exceptions. If your application logs errors itself then check that as well.

Comment: The error message clearly says that there are insufficient permissions. So why post here on SO?

Answer (score 1):

Grant the application pool identity or `IIS_IUSRS` group read permission on this `CIPET` folder if drive D is a local hard drive.

If drive D is a mapped drive, then you have to stop, and switch to a local drive or use UNC paths. IIS does not support mapped drives.